# Returned View does not open as a separate view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view which is having a partial view placed inside a ajax form. Upon the form submission I am returning another View but the problem is that the returned view is rendered in the earlier loaded main view only. It does not opens as a separate view.
 I think that the problem could be due to the use of ajax form which is calling the controller action method but I am not sure.
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Where's the code? And why are you using an AJAX form if you want a full postback?

Comment: See the raeson of using Ajax is that few part of the same maion view is rendered but for a diffrent functionality we need to call a diffrent view altogether

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior with ajax. Btw you are not using Ajax, but Ajah as you are returning HTML and not XML/JSON.

Ajax will not open a new page or popup without writing javascript code. Ajax is a way to transmit data between the current page and the server.

If you use Ajax.BeginForm, you can specify the ID of the dom element in which the HTML returned from your action should be attached.

If you use Html.BeginForm, you are not using ajax at all.

Comment: *Btw you are not using Ajax, but Ajah as you are returning HTML and not XML/JSON.* Never gonna catch on.

Comment: As I told in the answer I am returning a new View and that should be rendered separately so whatever means Ajax form or normal form used n the earlier loaded view got to do with the return of new View, but if it is telling browser to renderit there only , then I would like to know why ? and how?

Comment: There is no magic, but you are a beginner which don't understand the magic. This is normal, but to help you either you post your code and we can help quickly, either you go take a one week lesson (i give asp.net mvc lessons) and you'll be a crack in one week.